# Why am I getting result NONE in this simple python program?

Tags: python

I'm learning python 3. I expect this program to sum together a decreasing sequence of integers. Instead, I get NONE.

If this was throwing an error I might be able to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but in this case I am stumped.

```
def add_many_things(init_value):
    accumulator = 0
    while init_value > 0 :
        accumulator = accumulator + init_value
        init_value = init_value - 1

result = add_many_things(37)
print(f"{result}")
```

Comment: the function is missing ``return statement``, the default return value is ``None``

Comment: Where were you expecting any result to come from?  The function contains no `return` statement, Python is hardly going to try to guess which variable holds the value of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def add_many_things(init_value):
    accumulator = 0
    while init_value > 0 :
        accumulator = accumulator + init_value
        init_value = init_value - 1
    return accumulator

result = add_many_things(37)
print(f"{result}")
```

You miss to add the `return` statement to the `add_many_things` function.
Python allows this case and evaluate the return value to `None`.

Comment: Thank you. I am embarrassed and clearly sleep deprived.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `return  accumulator` to the function. You're trying to assign the result of the function:

> result = add_many_things(37)

but your `add_many_things()` function doesn't return a value. Adding the return statement at the end of the function will pass the value of `accumulator` back to the caller.

Comment: This **does** answer the question, but it was automatically flagged as low quality because of the short length. To avoid having that happen in the future, try to provide more complete answers with explanations.